# Loss is decreasing correctly but upon prediction, totally wrong results

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn

I've made a pretty basic stock prediction RNN with it's only input being the past stock price from apple. On this case, I want to input the apple stock price and the samsung stock price (2 features). I have created a timestep of 120 days.

Data preprocessing:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd, datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

#Desired dates
start = dt.datetime(2008, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 1, 26)

#Stock data retreive
entire_apple_dataset = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)
entire_samsung_dataset = web.DataReader("005930.KS", "yahoo", start, end)

#Joining the 2 datasets and filling in missing data
mixed_datasets = pd.concat([entire_apple_dataset, entire_samsung_dataset], axis=1)
mixed_datasets = mixed_datasets.fillna(method="ffill")

#Grabbing both high values for each stock price and inputting them into a list
entire_set = np.concatenate((mixed_datasets.iloc[:, 0:1].values, mixed_datasets.iloc[:, 6:7].values), axis=1)

#Normalizing each column separately
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc_apple = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
sc_samsung = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
entire_set[:,0:1] = sc_apple.fit_transform(entire_set[:,0:1])
entire_set[:,1:2] = sc_samsung.fit_transform(entire_set[:,1:2])

training_set = entire_set[:-16, :]

# Creating a data structure with 120 timesteps and 1 output
X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(120, training_set.shape[0]):
    X_train.append(training_set[i-120:i, :])
    y_train.append(training_set[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
```

The actual RNN

```
#--------------------------RNN-----------------------------------
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 100))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
#--------------------------RNN--------------------------------------------
```

Predicting data

```
inputs = entire_set[-120-16:,:]


X_test = []
for i in range(120, len(inputs)):
    X_test.append(training_set[i-120:i, :])
X_test = np.array(X_test)

predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc_apple.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
real_stock_price = entire_apple_dataset.iloc[:, 0:1].values
real_stock_price = real_stock_price[-16:,:]
```

As said on the beggining, it's predictions are awful. Not only the price is ages away, also the trend isn't accurate at all.
My only objective here is to predict the trend.

Comment: From my experience at least, LSTM models tend to be more suited to predicting a highly volatile time series, e.g. small-cap stocks. Blue-chip companies like AAPL tend to have a very defined trend, and therefore the LSTM model carries forward too much volatility from previous forecasts. My suggestion is to try something more simple such as ARIMA - if you obtain better forecasts then LSTMs might not be appropriate for this type of data.

Comment: That could be it, but the fact that when I graph it, it just shows me two straight lines with no correlation what so ever, tends to make me think that the error is in the code. As mentioned, I've previously done the exact same thing but with a single identifier and it worked pretty good.

Comment: Interesting. I would say that if the simpler model is giving better forecasts, then I would be inclined to go with that.

Comment: Are you sure the way Im inputting the 2 identifiers is correct? I say this because it's not that the simpler model is giving better forecasts, it's the fact that this model is giving forecasts which make no sense whatsoever, as if it had trained with a complete different training set.

Comment: Just for some background, can I ask why you are using a for loop when creating X_train and Y_train? (Not saying this is wrong, just to understand the model better). If it helps, here is another example of how an LSTM can be used to analyse time series: https://www.michael-grogan.com/hotel-cancellations-lstm/

Comment: Using a for loop in order to separate the X_train from the Y_train. So, 120 previous prices (x_train) to predict the next (y_train)

Comment: Sounds about right. My only conclusion would be that LSTM simply isn't a good fit for the data you are trying to analyse.